# Plotting Fourier Series of shifted square wave in Octave/Matlab

Tags: matlab, octave

The matlab code below produces the graph shown also. I am struggling to figure out why my FS curve is not following the square wave curve.

```matlab
N = 50;

T0 = -2;
Tf = 2;
T = Tf - T0;
DeltaT = T/4000;
t = T0:DeltaT:Tf;

n = (0:N).';
omega = (2.*pi.*n)./T;

u = @(t) heaviside(t);
f = u(t+1) - u(t);

a0 = (1./T) .* trapz(DeltaT,f);

an = (2./T) .* trapz(DeltaT, f.*cos(omega.*t));
bn = (2./T) .* trapz(DeltaT, f.*sin(omega.*t));

F = an.*cos(omega.*t) + bn.*sin(omega.*t);

FS = a0 + sum(F,1);

figure(1);
clf
hold on
plot(t,f,'k');
plot(t,FS,'r');
axis([-3 3 -3 3]);
grid on;
```

[incorrect fourier series of square wave](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMpAW.png)

Comment: `trapz` integrates along the columns by default. You probably want to do `trapz(DeltaT, ..., 2)`.

Comment: thank you! Now the problem is that my FS curve is vertically offset from the square wave.

Comment: if I change `FS = a0 + sum(F,1);` to `FS = sum(F,1) - a0;` it matches perfectly